# How to formally prove that $f(n)=\Theta f(n+1)$

Tags: asymptotics

How to formally prove that $f(n)=\Theta f(n+1)$?

It's supposed to be easy, but I still can't get it.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Beware the abuse of notation there.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the sequence $(f(n))$. For example:

- If $f(n)=n!$ then $f(n)\ll f(n+1)$ hence $f(n)\notin\Theta(f(n+1))$.
- If $f(n)=\frac1{n!}$ then $f(n)\gg f(n+1)$ hence $f(n)\notin\Theta(f(n+1))$.
- If $f(n)=a^n$ with $a\ne0$ then $f(n)=\frac1af(n+1)$ hence $f(n)\in\Theta(f(n+1))$.

Comment: oh OK then. I was wrong I thought they are Θ of each other. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: This (abuse of) notation suggests that numbers can be in Landau relations. I think you should properly define the two sequences behind the scenes as to not confuse anybody.